# VS code integrated terminal fails to run Python code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently having trouble running my Python code on the VS code integrated terminal, although the code runs perfectly on any other editor or on Powershell (Windows user).

I currently am using the Anaconda version of Python (Anaconda on PATH), but after some updates to VS code last night, errors are preventing me from running code on the integrated terminal. I tried reinstalling both Anaconda and VS code, but the problem persists.

At line:1 char:41

- ... onda3/python.exe" "c:/Users/Kun Hwi/programming/Python/pythonwork.py"
- ```
  Unexpected token '"c:/Users/Kun Hwi/programming/Python/pythonwork.py"' in expression or statement.

  + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
  ```

This happens for any code that I run, even for print('Hello world'). What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem with another extension it was caused or rather say in conflict with my terminal customization. More info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal 
When i removed it, the file worked fine. If this is the case, it is probably problem with the Extension and not with VS Code, so you might consider to contact the developer of it...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whatever extension you're using to execute your code is having issues escaping the file path such that PowerShell doesn't think there's a formatting problem (it has nothing to do with the Python code itself).